# Why are these Windows updates listed as "superseded" in the Windows Update Catalog but are still installable?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-update, updates

Consider the following KB updates according to the [Windows Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/) for Windows 7 (x64):

```
KB2574819
KB2732059
KB2834140
KB2919469
KB2970228
KB3006137
KB3102429
```

These updates, among others, are specifically listed as being superseded by `KB3125574`, which is considered to be the "SP2" update rollup for Windows 7.

However, after installing Windows 7 SP1 along with `KB3125574`, these updates are not only still installable (I am not given a dialog stating that the update is already installed or not applicable) but are even recommended by Windows Update itself.

Why does the Windows Update Catalog state that they are superseded when neither the system or Microsoft's update servers agree with this?

Comment: If they weren't still available, someone, somewhere, would be complaining about that too. They're still available for anyone who needs them. Better to keep them around than just throw them away. Basically, the whole lot is abandonware now, so they just keep it around for anybody who might still want to pick through the bones of a discontinued OS.

Answer (score 0):

First, the Windows Update Catalog is certainly not perfect, but we should
be thankful that it exists at all.

Second, a superseded update was not superseded at some past time, and was
then installed on millions of computers. It was perhaps superseded
at a future date, but there is no guarantee that without it being
installed first, that the new superseding update will succeed.

Windows Update usually follows the original
chronological order of the updates.
It may try to optimize on the number of the updates to be installed
(we don't have any detailed information on how),
but it will also install updates that might be superfluous,
according to the rule of
[better safe than sorry](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/better+(to+be)+safe+than+sorry).
Myself, I would prefer it that way.

Comment: Are you saying that even though an update may be listed as superseded by a later update it may still require the previous update to be installed first for the update to succeed?

Comment: It's entirely possible, because in real life that's what had worked, and I'm sure that Microsoft never tested anything else. Skipping a superseded update might work in many cases, but there could always be exceptions, to be discovered the hard way.

Comment: @Zhro - updates that are replaced (superseded) are definitely not required.

Answer (score 0):

Those updates were valid at some point, and considering the fact that there may be multiple files being updated by a package it has to at least *attempt* to run through it's script to attempt to update files.

It may be smart enough to check file versions and dates of signatures and only update from versions older than what it contains, but if it has even one file that it can update, then it still has to run through all of them to check.

The actual package installer itself is basically a dumb installer and has no way to know that it has been *completely* superseded another update. They are small, compact executables that are intended to be run by a much smarter system, Windows Update, to establish whether they are valid for installation. If they contained all the "check whether I am valid on this system" logic then each update would be far larger, would have to connect to the internet to check and would therefore be difficult to install on air-gapped systems.

Alternatively Microsoft would have to regenerate *every* previous update with a "don't install if you find this later update" instruction. That would be a massive amount of work that is largely unnecessary when they have another tool that does the job for them: Windows Update.

Comment: Can you clarify why these updates are still recommended by Windows Update when the subsequent update that supersedes them has already been installed?

Comment: Presumably because while they might be "superseded" no one clicked the box in the backend to mark it as obsolete. If letting it attempt to install is harmless due to checks performed by the package then there is no problem with letting it install and adding whatever entry is required for it in the internal database maintained by Windows Update. The deep workings of Windows Update is a question for Microsoft, and on an obsolete operating system is a question very likely to be ignored.